# Dual boot CentOS 7 and CentOS 8 on UEFI machine

Tags: centos, dual-boot, uefi, boot-loader, multiboot

I want to build a dual boot environment of CentOS 7 and 8 on a UEFI/GPT machine.

But, I encountered a EFI bootloader problem;
Both CentOS 7 and 8 installers put their bootloaders in the same place: `\EFI\centos`.
So, the previous one will be overwritten by after one.

To avoid this conflict, I tried the following workaround:

1. Install CentOS 7
2. Install CentOS 8 without bootloader (ESP not modified),
3. Boot CentOS 7 and make boot menu entries using `grub2-mkconfig` and `os-prober`.

This looks succeeded but also looks weird.
If there is a way to put the bootloaders in ESP separately and list those by the EFI boot manager, I think that's better than above.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to put the bootloaders in ESP separately?
- If no, the workaround I wrote above is correct?

Thank you

P.S. I know I can build individual virtual environments using VirtualBox etc, but I actually need a dual boot environment now for some reason.

Comment: you should be able to set it during install for centos8. But just out of curiosity... why do you want this?